# At what level should i do checks?

Tags: oop

I design new class, which contains the same function `boolean isCellEmpty()` at each level of abstraction. I have the `Matrix` class in the bottom of my class hierarchy. On the top I have `GraphMainWindow` class.

Where should I do checks (e.g. `if (i >= 0, i < xCellsCount, j >= 0` and so...)?

Comment: Thanks for answers! But i'm sorry, when i described my hierarchy i didn't mean `inherits` relation. I meant that `GraphMainWindow` uses `Graph`, that uses `GraphModel`, that is superclass of `MatrixGraphModel`, that uses `Matrix`.

Comment: Does "cell" mean the same thing throughout the hierarchy? Does `isCellEmpty()` test the same thing?

Comment: Little bit different purposes. But in general it does. (In all the hierarchy I do same checks.)

Comment: In this case, implement the method at the point where it starts to mean something. Also, make the meaning clearer with different method names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, wondered about it myself many times. Answer: In the lowest level. This way errors will never slip undetected.
You can still check for errors in higher level where an algorithmic process makes sense, but the lowest level is the most important.

There are some exceptions to this. For example, if the error is reported via a message that holds the applicatio and you expect many errors to occur in the lowest level. But these are not so common, and you can bend the above rule if you feel it disturbs you.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: at the most generic level possible. The first inheritable class that declares those variables should perform the checks. Anything below that should just defer to the superclass unless overridden functionality is required. In a class further up the inheritance hierarchy from the one you've chosen to use for the checks, the method handling the checks should probably notify subclasses that haven't implemented an overridden version that they're getting default (and possibly useless) behavior. I often raise an exception in such a case.

Answer (score 1):

So to put it in a nutshell you have this classes diagram:

```
Matrix        ( a
   ^            ^
   |            |
  ...           b means : b inherits a)
   ^
   |
```

GraphMainWindow

You have a method `isCellEmpty` that is found in the base class and every inherited one.
If the datastruct of data that  `isCellEmpty` use to do its checks do not change since the `Matrix` class, you do them in the `Matrix` class which is the most generic one.

If you change the datastructure since the `Matrix` one you should implement the test in the class that changed the datastructure.

Regards